# Usage of the spatial "from"

Tags: prepositions

Are there any grammatical correctness and fluency differences between these sentences:

> 1. Depends on the side you look from
> 2. Depends on the side from which you look
> 3. Depends on the side which you look from

in spatial terms?

Comment: What do you want it to mean? What is the context of this?

Comment: @Oscar I'm not sure what you want to say, but there's one similar, common phrase: *It depends on how you look at it.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually

> from

describes a point of departure or perspective.

All three of your sentences are understandable, but it might be more parsimonious to say

> *(It)* depends **from** which side you look.

Comment: What do you mean by saying: it would be parsimonious to say that?

Comment: [parsimonious](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parsimonious#mw-head) = frugal, less verbose, fewer words, more direct.